# Automapper: Converting to model that has multiple constructors

Tags: automapper, structuremap

```
//Mapping:
this.CreateMap<PartModel, Part>().ConstructUsingServiceLocator();

//Model
[Table("Car")]
public class Car
{
    public Car(IUser user)
    {
    }

    public Car()
    {
    }
    public IList<Part> Parts { get; set; }
}



  [Table("Part")]
public class Part
{
    public Part(IUser user)
    {
    }

    public Part()
    {
    }

}

public class CarsViewModel
{
    public IList<PartViewModel> Parts{ get; set; }
}
```

I am using ConstructorUsingServiceLocator() so that Automapper instantiates the Part model using the constructor with the IUser parameter. 
When I do the following mapping:

```
//carViewModel holds multiple parts
var car = this.mapper.Map<Car>(carViewModel);
```

car holds multiple part models. However they all have identical properties. Looks like the constructor is only called once and the object is being re used. I am using structure map as my DI container. Is there an easy way to not reuse the part object?

Answer (score 0):

If you have IUser as a parameter of the first class to be mapped to the second class constructor parameter, you can use.

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<FromT, ToT>()
    .ForCtorParam("CtorParamName", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.MyIUser))
);
```